# Is there a history for regsvr32 stored in the event log?

Tags: windows, dll, event-log, regsvr32

I am trying to submit a bug report to a project and I need to look up what dll was registered with windows today to include it in the report. (Running another program that registered a DLL fixed the program I was originally using and I want to let the developer know.)

Is there any place in the event log to see a history of registered and unregistered DLLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regsvr32 inserts entries into the registry.
If you run a diff between the registry as it was before and after the regsvr32, you would be able to find out what exactly was registered.

ProcMon is also a tool that you can use to monitor registry changes

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: I don't think this works for the OP, since he didn't capture the state of the registry at the beginning of the day.

Comment: Oh well, I did end up figuring it out anyway. For those curious the dll in question was `IViewers.dll` regestered by the OLE/Com Object Viewer in the windows SDK.